# Is it possible to check a generic part of a string in Excel?

Tags: string, excel

Given an IP in string form (XX.XXX.YYY.XX) is it possible to check the values of YYY and copy them into an adjacent cell?

The value will either be 2 or 3 characters long and will always come after the 2nd period.

Answered below by Jerry. Thank you again Jerry!

Comment: What do you mean by 'check the values of YYY'?

Comment: I need to take the values where YYY are and copy them to another cell.

So if I have 10.111.124.2 I need to get 124 and copy it to another cell.

Comment: I thought about using a search but while the first 2 values will always be 10, the 2nd and 3rd values are either 2 or 3 characters long. So 10.111.12.4 is one, and 10.11.234.7 is also a value. Im not sure how to isolate what I want to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract `YYY` into a cell with the formula:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",2))+1,FIND(".",A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",2))+1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",2))-1)
```

Assuming the IP is in A1.

It works for whatever length of IP you have.

**EDIT:** Some details:

There's some bits of recycled formulas here. `SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",2)` returns `XX.XXX@YYY.XX` (substitute the 2nd occurrence of the dot in A1 by `@`) We'll use this in the big formula and let's call it `R` for the time being.

This turns the formula into:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("@",R)+1,FIND(".",A1,FIND("@",R)+1)-FIND("@",R)-1)
        ^-----------^ ^--------------------------------------^
            Start     |           1            | |     2     |
                                      Length
```

Much better!

The starting position part:

`FIND("@",R)+1` returns the position of the character just after `@`, so that `MID` starts with the first `Y`. Here, the position becomes 7.

The length position part:

1. `FIND(".",A1,FIND("@",R)+1)` There's a formula we already used here, `FIND("@",R)+1` is 7 so that we have: `FIND(".",A1,7)`. This finds the position of the dot in A1 which is after or at the 7th character. This one gets the value 10.
2. This one should be familiar and gets the position of `@` in `R`, which is 6.

`10-6` gives 4, which is one character longer than what we're looking for. (because we're dealing with ranked positions; e.g. Length of the string between 1st and 3nd character of a string is 1 but 3-1 gives 2)

Hence why there's the final -1 part.

Comment: From what I understand you are making a substring starting in the middle. The first start value you find the first period and then increase the index by one, for the second one I get kind of lost...

Comment: Okay, I'll add an explanation in a bit :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it. Edit: Confirming this worked, Jerry is awesome!